# Filter and Order by Multiple Custom Meta Values

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I am trying to query a custom post type, order by a custom meta value, and only display posts with a different custom meta value.

I am able to do each independently but not both at the same time.

Here is the current code.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'shows',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'meta_key' => 'show_location',
            'meta_value' => 'second'
            )
    )
);                  
// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

My **NEW** code as a result from the answer below:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'shows',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'key' => 'show_location',
            'value' => 'second'
            )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple meta value you have to use "IN"

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'shows',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'key' => 'show_location',
            'value' => array('second','third'),
            'compare' => 'IN'
            )
    )
);                  
// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The IN comparison checks for the post to be available with the values that are present in the 'meta_value' array.

Comment: Thank you! Removing meta_ from my meta_query did the trick.